# How to read a file line by line and making a new file for each line having same filename as last word of each line?

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose the file contents are:

```
May 30, Thu,    England vs SouthAfrica,     Match 1 ,Afternoon, London
May 31, Fri,    Windies vs Pakistan,    Match 2 ,Afternoon, Nottingham
Jun 01, Sat,    NewZealand vs SriLanka, Match 3 ,Afternoon, Cardiff
```

I want to create three files each having names London, Nottingham and Cardiff. Each file must have its own line. Like,content of Nottingham should be:

```
May 31, Fri,    Windies vs Pakistan,    Match 2 ,Afternoon
```

I don't want to use awk. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you try and why you don't want to use awk?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here you can ① post your code (as a [mcve]), ② describe what you observe it does (with which input), and ③ describe what you expect to observe instead.  This results in a clear question which can be answered.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

cat datafile| \
while read line
do
    lastword=${line##*,}
    echo $lastword
    echo $line > $lastword
done
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how **cat datafile| \** and lastword=${line##*,} working here

Comment: The cat datafile pipes the content of the datafile into the read binary one line at a time.

Comment: The "line##*," blob is telling bash to split the line using the "," delimiter and output the last match.